# Android - log.d causes program to crash

Tags: java, android, logging, nullpointerexception

I have a for loop with alot of lines, and a line in it is causing a NullPointerException. So I went to place a log.d after every line to find out which exact line was causing the error.

Initially, it looks like this

```
for(int i = 0;i<(int)db.countScores();i++){
        Log.d("UserLog","hello");
        //creating layout to hold views
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //creating gamemode textview
        Log.d("UserLog","step 1");
        final TextView gameMode = new TextView(this);
        Log.d("UserLog","step 2");
        gameMode.setText(db.getScoreData("game_type")[i]);
        Log.d("UserLog","step 3");
        int density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        Log.d("UserLog","step 4");
        gameMode.setTextSize((int)25 * density);
        LayoutParams gameModelp = new LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        gameModelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        gameModelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        Log.d("UserLog","step 5");
        gameMode.setLayoutParams(gameModelp);
        Log.d("UserLog","step 6");
        gameMode.setId(1100+i);
        Log.d("UserLog","step 7");
        relativeLayout.addView(gameMode);
        Log.d("UserLog","step 8");
        final TextView corrects = new TextView(this);
        Log.d("UserLog","step 9");
        corrects.setText(db.getScoreData("corrects")[i]);
        Log.d("UserLog","step 10");
        corrects.setTextSize((int)25 * density);
        ... moar code
}
```

And the output: shows "step 1, step 2, step 3....." all the way until 10 and it crashes with a null pointer exception

I didnt know what was wrong with the line right after step 10, so i went to make more logs for the next 30 lines. Ironically, it outputs from step 1 all the way until step 30 with a nullpointerexception again.

Can anyone advice me with what to do? I can post the full code (without the log.ds) but its pretty lengthy.

**EDIT - LOGCAT**

```
08-30 14:58:25.477: D/AndroidRuntime(12339): Shutting down VM
08-30 14:58:25.477: W/dalvikvm(12339): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4165d700)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vsifc.elderlyapp/com.vsifc.elderlyapp.ReviewScoresActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at com.vsifc.elderlyapp.ReviewScoresActivity.onCreate(ReviewScoresActivity.java:120)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    ... 11 more
```

http://pastebin.com/bTZcgZMA

**Full code**

```
        final TextView gameMode = new TextView(this);
        gameMode.setText(db.getScoreData("game_type")[i]);
        int density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        gameMode.setTextSize((int)25 * density);
        LayoutParams gameModelp = new LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        gameModelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        gameModelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        gameMode.setLayoutParams(gameModelp);
        gameMode.setId(1100+i);
        relativeLayout.addView(gameMode);
        final TextView corrects = new TextView(this);
        corrects.setText(db.getScoreData("corrects")[i]);
        corrects.setTextSize((int)25 * density);
        LayoutParams correctslp = new LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        correctslp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1100+i);
        corrects.setLayoutParams(correctslp);
        corrects.setId(1200+i);
        relativeLayout.addView(corrects);
        final TextView wrongs = new TextView(this);
        wrongs.setText(db.getScoreData("wrongs")[i]);
        wrongs.setTextSize((int)25 * density);
        LayoutParams wrongslp = new LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        wrongslp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1100+i);
        wrongslp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,1200+i);
        wrongs.setLayoutParams(wrongslp);
        wrongs.setId(1300+i);
        relativeLayout.addView(wrongs);
        final TextView rate = new TextView(this);
        int tempValue1 = Integer.parseInt((db.getScoreData("corrects")[i]));
        int tempValue2 = Integer.parseInt((db.getScoreData("wrongs")[i]));
        float tempValue3 = tempValue1/tempValue2;
        tempValue3*=100;
        double tempValue4 = Math.floor(tempValue3);
        rate.setText(String.valueOf(tempValue4) + "%");
        rate.setTextSize((int)25 * density);
        LayoutParams ratelp = new LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ratelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1100+i);
        ratelp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,1300+i);
        rate.setLayoutParams(wrongslp);
        rate.setId(1400+i);
        relativeLayout.addView(rate);
        theLayout.addView(relativeLayout); //line 120
```

Comment: also post the line which causes the error

Comment: i posted the log as a pastebin. I cant find the line with the error in the first place

Comment: Which line is it throwing the null exception on? A reference to a database is null? Logcat will give a line number.

Comment: What is at ReviewScoresActivity.java in line no 120?

Comment: what is Line 120 in ReviewScoresActivity.java ??

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 14:58:25.487: E/AndroidRuntime(12339):    at com.vsifc.elderlyapp.ReviewScoresActivity.onCreate(ReviewScoresActivity.java:120)`  What is at line 120?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and learn how to use the debugger.  With respect, those Log lines are madness.  Log is for, er, logging, not for debugging.  You will save yourself a whole heap of time and frustration and also gain a vital skill for programming.

Comment: I suspect `db.getScoreData("corrects")` is returning null.

Comment: line 120 is adding a view to the layout

Comment: Well, that's the line causing the NPE so please show it!

Comment: yeah i just pasted the full code in

Comment: Have you changed this code since you posted the logcat? The line you have shown cannot cause an NPE since rate cannot be null (it's referenced in the line above) and relativeLayout cannot be null since you added wrongs to it earlier on.  I think you need to rethink this, and take my advice, use the debugger.

Comment: my bad, line 120 was the line right after it. I solved the problem, apparently it was becuase the layout was defined wrongly. Sorry for all the trouble caused. However now i have a separate issue about the views not being visible but i think i'll create a separate question for that.

Comment: @chesnutcase please formulate your last comment as an answer and accept it so that this question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

-resolved-
copy paste:
my bad, line 120 was the line right after it. I solved the problem, apparently it was becuase the layout was defined wrongly. Sorry for all the trouble caused. However now i have a separate issue about the views not being visible but i think i'll create a separate question for that